# WordPress 3 Custom Post Type: How to get comments

Tags: wordpress, comments, custom-post-type

I am using 4 Custom Post Types each having this kind of declaration:

```
register_post_type( 'texts', array(
    'labels'=>array('name'=>'Texts','singular_name'=>'Text'),
    'public'=>true,
    'has_archive'=>true,
    'menu_position'=>5
) );
```

The problem I have is that posts in these pages do not get Comment links, saying comments are closed.

There is a Page created called Texts with a slug of /texts/ which has a custom template for blog posts, but that does enable comments.

How can I get comments to work please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the 'supports' parameter here,
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

or:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support
for example:
add_post_type_support('texts','comments');

My example code, copied from my theme's functions.php:

```
// uses sd_register_post_type, which is from http://somadesign.ca/projects/smarter-custom-post-types/, not necessary anymore with WP3.1

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types', 0 ); // before sd_register_post_type's actions
function create_post_types(){
   $post_supports = array(
     'title'
    ,'editor'
    ,'author'
    ,'thumbnail'
    ,'excerpt'
    ,'trackbacks'
    ,'custom-fields'
    ,'comments'
    ,'revisions'
  );

  $post_type_slug = 'my-news'; // max 20 chars!
  $post_type_slug_plural = $post_type_slug;
  sd_register_post_type( $post_type_slug, array(
    'labels' => array(
               'name' => 'My News',
      'singular_name' => 'My New' // :)
    )
   ,'rewrite' => array(
     'slug' => $post_type_slug
    ,'with_front' => false // don't prepend /blog/...
   )
   ,'public' => true
   ,'hierarchical' => false
   ,'supports' => $post_supports
   ,'menu_position' => 6
   ,'capability_type' => 'post'
  ),$post_type_slug_plural);
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomies_for_custom_post_types', 11 ); // 11=after sd_register_post_type's actions
function register_taxonomies_for_custom_post_types(){
  $post_type_slug = 'my-news'; // max 20 chars!
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', $post_type_slug);
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', $post_type_slug);
}

add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );
function build_taxonomies(){
  $post_types = array( 'post', /*'page',*/ 'my-news' );
  register_taxonomy( 'city', $post_types,
    array(
      'public' => true
     ,'labels' => array(
                 'name' => 'Cities',
        'singular_name' => 'City'
      )
     ,'hierarchical' => true
     ,'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'my-news/cities'
       ,'with_front' => false // don't prepend /blog/...
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. I've added the supports in the array parameters for `register_post_type` function but nothing happens. In the wp-admin I don't get the `Allow Comments` checkbox and in the public section it just says `Comments are closed.`. What's wrong?

Comment: Hi, comments can be disabled/enabled per post base too, at the bottom of the post editor page. Is it enabled for your test post?

I use these parameters (with sd_register_post_type func):

`'labels' => array( 'name' => 'News', 'singular_name' => 'News' )
,'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $post_type_slug ,'with_front' => false )
,'public' => true
,'hierarchical' => false
,'supports' => array(
     'title'
    ,'editor'
    ,'author'
    ,'thumbnail'
    ,'excerpt'
    ,'trackbacks'
    ,'custom-fields'
    ,'comments'
    ,'revisions'
  )
,'menu_position' => 6
,'capability_type' => 'post'`

Comment: Hi, biziclop. Your comment didn't fit. :) You should add it to your answer, please.

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer above, hope you can find something useful in it :)